# C# WinForm how to format a form programmatically only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, formatting

Currently I am working on generate a form (WinForm) programmatically according to the given format file. This feature is used for generating forms like product specifications.

The given format file is a text file, its extension is unknown yet, it could be `.txt`. This format file might change in the future according to the needs, for now, it looks like:

```
[Hardware]
          [Voltage]
                   [Range]
                   [Accuracy]
          [Current]
                   [Range]
                   [Time]
                   [Precision]
[Software]
          [Set up]
                   [A]
                   [B]
                   [C]
          [Require]
                   [E]
                   [F]
...
```

And my program should read this format file and generate a form accordingly, like:
[image]

This form would later be filled with data from a given Excel file, but I can worry about this part later, for now I only need to worry about how to read from the format file and generate a form.
Any tip would be super helpful. Thank you in advance!

**Edit 1:** the format file can be anything, I am using `.xml` file for the format now:

```
<regionList>
    <region id="1">
        <regionName>Hardware</regionName>
        <modules>
            <module1>Voltage</module1>
                <components>
                    <component1>Range</component1>
                    <component2>Accuracy</component2>
                </components>
            <module2>Current</module2>
                <components>
                    <component1>Range</component1>
                    <component2>Time</component2>
                    <component3>Precision</component3>
                </components>
        </modules>
    <\region>
    <region id="2">
       <regionName>Software</regionName>
        <modules>
            <module1>Set Up</module1>
                <components>
                    <component1>A</component1>
                    <component2>B</component2>
                    <component3>C</component3>
                </components>
            <module2>Require</module2>
                <components>
                    <component1>D</component1>
                    <component2>E</component2>
                </components>
        </modules>
    <\region>
...
<\regionList>
```

Comment: I strongly advise to re-think the format to rely on an existing definition language like XML, JSON or YAML. That will **greatly** simplify the work you need to do to write and parse these files, and well as improve quality and performance,  because you will be able to rely on existing battle-tested parsers and tools. Don't reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn this format looks a bit like YAML. Beyond that though, the question is asking how to create an entire application from scratch. Something best done with the current designer.

Comment: @EmoryLu Maybe you should devide and conquer: First step - How to construct a form's content dynamically in code. Second step - how to inform that process through some sort of configuration file.

Comment: BTW, by the looks of this -  have you considered some sort of Report-Engine?

Comment: You can try with TableLayoutPanel. RowSpan and ColumnSpan give you the possibility to merge cells.

Comment: When you talk about "I can worry about this part later" does that incorporate editing of that thing?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Hi, yes the format file doesn't have to be a `.txt` file, it can be anything, for now, I am using `.XML` file.

Comment: You could try to draw on a Bitmap with the graphics object. This way you can also print it.

Comment: @Ralf I am thing about using either `dataGridView` or `TableLayoutPanel` control to make the form once I read from the format file, these two controls can be simply fileld data later.